# Where do you put SQL RAISERROR code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to set up a custom error message to pass to MS Access (from SQL Server) when a user enters a duplicate key (instead of system message 2627).  I've read up on sp_addmessage and RAISERROR and TRY/CATCH blocks which all make perfect sense.  But nowhere I've looked does it seem to say where you put the RAISERROR code (and TRY/CATCH block) so it will actually pass back to the application. So, where does the code go?

Comment: RAISEERROR() is a sql function. You call it when there's an error you want returned. You don't have to encapsulate it in a stored procedure. It's already  available for usage where-ever you want to use it.

Comment: @StevenMays ok, I see.  I still don't know where to put my code that uses RAISERROR though.

Comment: You don't really need RAISERROR. Use an error handler in VBA to display a meaningful message. Here is an example:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/77c6075b-e18c-4598-a9d4-db2a91e8270c/trap-error-in-access-form-linked-to-sql-server-table?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think about it in terms of users entering duplicate keys. Instead, think in terms of users just entering keys, some of which turn out to be duplicates when you try to insert them. It's a subtle difference, but it helps you here, because it means you think in terms of having your code available for all new table inserts instead of just a specific type of insert.

When a user enters a key, an INSERT sql statement runs. If the key is a duplicate and you have the constraints defined on the table to the prevent that, the INSERT statement fails. If your Access application has you writing custom SQL, you can wrap this in a TRY/CATCH, and put the RAISERROR in the CATCH block. If your Access application is such that you never see any SQL, you may be stuck, and have to put up with the built-in behavior.

Comment: I'm running the app on a SQL Server backend that I'm developing myself, so yeah, I'm writing SQL.  If I'm reading your answer correctly, I'd put the TRY/CATCH in a constraint in the table's code?  I.e. in the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: Negative @Rominus, you'd put it in the INSERT statement.